# Passing static method as argument, no address-of operator required?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, static-methods, member-functions, address-operator

```
class ThreadWorker
{
public:
    ThreadWorker(void);
    virtual ~ThreadWorker(void);

    static void DoSomething();
};


int main()
{
    boost::thread thread1(ThreadWorker::DoSomething);
    boost::thread thread2(ThreadWorker::DoSomething);
    boost::thread thread3(&ThreadWorker::DoSomething);
}
```

I'm playing around with Boost.Thread and I notice it doesn't *seem* to matter whether I use the address of operator (&) or not when passing a static member function as an argument.  Does it not matter?  And if not, why?  Is one way more correct than the other?

Comment: What compiler are you using? The ones that I use these days complain to me when not using `&`, though older compilers were totally fine with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It effectively does not matter. Functions (free functions and static member functions, not non-static member functions) decay to function pointers. No way is more correct than the other, I happen to prefer the explicit one though.

**C++11 Standard, 4.3/1:**

> An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T.” The result is a pointer to the function.

**C++11 Standard, 5.2.2/1 - Function call:**

> There are two kinds of function call: ordinary function call and member function call. A static member function is an ordinary function.

Comment: I'm confused about this sentence: "Functions (non-member functions that is) decay to function pointers".  I'm talking about *member* functions, aren't I?

Comment: @User: A static function is not a member function.

Comment: Ok I believe you, but aren't they called "static member functions"?  Are you saying "static member functions" are not "member functions"?