# how to run a static function in a new thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

After searching trough the forum, i came across some answers nevertheles I could not get a clear answer to how to run a static method in a new thread in c++. My main concern is what is the best way to start a thread?(Is it working also from inside of another thread?)
which header is better to use? thread.h, pthread.h?

I would like to create a new thread(when a given method is called) and call inside this thread another function...
Any hints how I could approach this issue?

Thank you guys very much in advance!

Comment: This is OS specific, or at least it will be until std::thread is implemented by all compilers. (It's part of C++11).  Which OS are you using?

Comment: Looks like you should start from the basics of C++ language to understand what keyword "static" means.

Comment: BTW, here the example how to pass static member to thread with explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761527/passing-static-method-as-argument-no-address-of-operator-required

Answer (score 7):

There is no problem to run static member function in thread. Just use `std::thread` the same way as for free function:

```
#include <thread>

class Threaded
{
public:

   static void thread_func() {}

};

int main()
{
    std::thread t(Threaded::thread_func);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, starting thread will work from any other thread as well. With C++11 standard compliant compiler you shall use `#include <thread>`. Otherwise take a look at [`boost::thread`](http://www.boost.org/libs/thread/). It's usage is similar.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming for example your static function has two parameters:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

void launchThread()
{
    boost::thread t( &MyClass::MyStaticFunction, arg1, arg2 );
}
```

This will require linking to the [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/thread.html) library.

Answer (score 1):

The best OOPs way of doing this would be:
Define an **entry point** (`entryPoint()`) which will call a **member function**(`myThreadproc()`). The entry point will start the thread and call `myThreadproc`. Then you can access all the member variables and methods.

myClassA.h

```
class A
{
   static void *entryPoint(void *arg);
   void myThreadproc();
   void myfoo1();
   void myfoo2();
}
```

myClassA.cpp

```
void *A::entryPoint(void *arg)
{
   A *thisClass = (A *)arg;
   thisClass-> myThreadproc();
}

void A::myThreadproc()
{
       //Now this function is running in the thread..
       myfoo1();
       myfoo2();
}
```

Now you can create the thread like this:

```
int main()
{
   pthread_t thread_id; 
   pthread_create(&thread_id,NULL,(A::entryPoint),new A());
   //Wait for the thread
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `A::entryPoint` needs to return `void*`.

Comment: And I think you wanted to call `myThreadproc` in `entryPoint`, right?

Comment: True, but I usually only edit if the user doesn't do it in a while. +1 anyway.